# Select query in mysql using COALESCE

Tags: mysql, coalesce

I want to write a select statement that should filter data based on wildcard characters. I have written something like this but it doesn't serve my purpose:

```
Select r.CompanyID,r.Description,c.BusinessUnitID,c.BusinessSourceID as BusinessSrcID,
c.Description as BusinessDesc from RCompanyTable r
join CBusinessUnitTable c on r.CompanyID=c.CompanyID
WHERE r.CompanyID like CASE WHEN COALESCE('Regexp(*)', '') = '' THEN r.CompanyID ELSE 'Company2'  END
```

But in this it always executes the else part. 
**What i am looking for is it should give me all data when i pass * to the condition.
Since in my RCompanyTable i have two records Company1 and Company2, I want that if i pass * in that query then it should return me both company1 and company2 data but if i pass regexp(any1) it should provide me Comapany1 Data and if both conditions are not true then it should go to else part displaying Company2 data**
Looking forward to your answer.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE r.CompanyID = CASE WHEN r.CompanyId LIKE '%*%' THEN r.CompanyID ELSE 'Company2' END
```

This where clause returns all records where `companyID` has a * in it, or the `companyID` is Company2. Is this what you are after?

Comment: But still it executes the else part:( And yes i am looking for this with one more thing, i want to associate Case true part with regular expression so that if i pass wildcard or data, i should get data based on the condition else get data from else part

Comment: Are you sure you have the right field? CompanyId seems like it would be a number. Maybe you mean ComapnyName instead of CompanyId? It shouldn't hit the else if it has an asterisk in the field.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want with `*` and `regexp(any1)`, but assuming that they are constant strings, then this query should work:

```
SET @parameter = '';    

Select r.CompanyID
    , r.Description
    , c.BusinessUnitID
    , c.BusinessSourceID AS BusinessSrcID
    , c.Description AS BusinessDesc 
    FROM RCompanyTable r
    JOIN CBusinessUnitTable c ON r.CompanyID = c.CompanyID
    WHERE (@parameter LIKE '%*%' AND r.CompanyID IN ('Company1', 'Company2'))
        OR (@parameter LIKE 'regexp(any1)' AND r.CompanyID = 'Company1')
        OR (@parameter NOT IN ('%*%', 'regexp(any1)') AND r.CompanyID = 'Company2')
```

The `@parameter` is what you are going to pass in the query.